# Select2 produces very strange-looking form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, api, autocomplete, select2-rails

What am I doing wrong in my code that makes select2 behave so weirdly below?

1) I want the form to look as it should in the examples here, instead of what I have.
Examples:
http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/index.html#basics

2) I want data to POST and save correctly, but it's not saving to the database.

(please right click, then select "view image" to zoom in and read.)

[image: output html]

[image: my code]

I've followed the select2 API instructions.
https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails

Is the problem coming from gem conflicts, bootstrap conflicts, or perhaps the rails form helper I am using?

---

I've also looked at these threads, but I couldn't figure out the solution.

[preloading external json into select box then after search getting specific results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978623/preloading-external-json-into-select-box-then-after-search-getting-specific-resu)

[Select2 initSelection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112988/select2-initselection)

[Select2 does not create name attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276546/select2-does-not-create-name-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

Answer to issue #1 about weird form layout.

I haven't been able to get it to look exactly ilke the model, and there are other issues, but here is one big piece of the solution.

Under the application.css.scss file, you cannot use multiple comments sections. It needs to look like this:

```
/*
 *= require select2
 *= require select2-bootstrap
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

and NOT like this

```
/*
 *= require select2
 *= require select2-bootstrap
 */
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

I know, wtf, right? xp
It is what it is, though.

Hopefully this helps someone retain their head hair count. =]